# Ionic:Error: Failed to fetch platform android in Mac?

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

**Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Adding icons for platform: android
Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: version not found: cordova-android@5.1.1
**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just try:

```
rm -r ~/.cordova
```

If not work, which command did you exec before the error?

Comment: **ionic platform add android@5.0.0**

Answer (score 0):

Related - same error but for `cordova-ios@~4.4.0`even though I could SEE the folder sitting right there alongside cordova-android that built & ran just fine

... Updated, removed/reinstalled everything w/o success.

Eventually I updated npm itself:
`npm install -g npm@latest`

And ran `npm cache clean` ...

Now miraculously, Cordova can find the platform. 
iOS builds & runs fine in emulator.

Must've had an old version of npm or iOS leftover from PhoneGap or something clogging the pipes.